# VueJs Component with Tableau Embed Object not Refreshing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, embed, tableau-api

I am trying to make [Tableau Embed Code](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/embed_code.htm) into a VueJS component and it works fine on initial load, meaning the tableau dashboard displays just fine with the code below:

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: 'TableauFrame',
  props: {
    link: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    tabs: {
        type: String,
        default: "no"
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    let tableauScript = document.createElement('script')
    tableauScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://myserver.com/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js')
    document.head.appendChild(tableauScript)
  }
}

</script>

<template>
  <div class="viz">
  </div>
    <object class='tableauViz' id="tableauFrame" width='100%' height='850' style='display:none;'>
      <param name='host_url' value='https://myserver.com/' />
      <param name='embed_code_version' value='3' />
      <param name='site_root' value='' />
      <param name='name' :value='link' />
      <param name='tabs' :value='tabs'  />
      <param name='toolbar' value='yes' />
      <param name='showAppBanner' value='false' />
      <param name='filter' value='iframeSizedToWindow=true' />
    </object>
</template>

<style>

</style>
```

The problem arises when the `link` prop gets updated the embed object link does not get updated and I am not sure why. I've tried different solutions such as dynamically building the embed object and inserting into the DOM but that does not work at all... not even on initial load.

Any idea on how to get an embed object URL to refresh appropriately?

Comment: I tried to adapt this https://officert.github.io/vue-friendly-iframe/#/home to work with an embed object but I was unsuccessful...

Comment: On page load, Tableau deletes the object element completely and creates an iframe based on the param tag values. Since the object element no longer exists, the prop update doesn't do anything.

I've had success using the new viz() method and doing it all in JS. Check out [this file](https://github.com/masenius/tableau-react-embed/blob/master/src/TableauReport.jsx), though it's React and not Vue, it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: I did not know Tableau had an API, super useful!!

Comment: @SunilKumar do you have an example of your vue js integration with tableau for getdata() api?

Comment: @Rizakha - https://github.com/edocbuhtig/tableau-integration-vue-js